# What is the name of this kind of pass, done with the outside of the foot?

Tags: football, technique

I found a [thread in Twitter](https://twitter.com/LioneI10i/status/1036273592135118851) where they show a pass by Lionel Messi.

[image]

Next messages show others players performing it such as David Silva.

[image]

Is there a specific name for this kind of pass or is it just a *pass with the outside of the foot*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique of putting curl on a ball with the outside of the foot is known as a **trivela**, which is a Portuguese term. Another notable example would be Roberto Carlos' bending free kick against France in 1997.

There is as far as I know no specific word for a *pass* with the outside of the foot specifically.